# when I run React Native Application on iOS physical device, It is just got stuck after showing Building and some logs in terminal

Tags: iphone, react-native, runtime-error, cross-platform, freeze

info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace LoginProject.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme LoginProject -destination id=00008020-000509823C89002E")

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace LoginProject.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme LoginProject -destination id=00008020-000509823C89002E

User defaults from command line:
IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages

ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (96 targets)
Target 'LoginProject' in project 'LoginProject'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Pods-LoginProject' in project 'Pods' via file 'libPods-LoginProject.a' in build phase 'Link Binary'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'AppAuth' in project 'Pods' via options '-lAppAuth' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' in project 'Pods' via options '-lCocoaAsyncSocket' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods' via options '-lDoubleConversion' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFirebaseAppCheckInterop' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseAuth' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFirebaseAuth' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCore' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFirebaseCore' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCoreInternal' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFirebaseCoreInternal' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseInstallations' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFirebaseInstallations' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Boost-iOSX' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Boost-iOSX' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Fmt' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Fmt' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Folly' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Folly' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-PeerTalk' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-PeerTalk' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FlipperKit' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipperKit' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'GTMAppAuth' in project 'Pods' via options '-lGTMAppAuth' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'GTMSessionFetcher' in project 'Pods' via options '-lGTMSessionFetcher' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'GoogleSignIn' in project 'Pods' via options '-lGoogleSignIn' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'GoogleUtilities' in project 'Pods' via options '-lGoogleUtilities' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'PromisesObjC' in project 'Pods' via options '-lPromisesObjC' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCT-Folly' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRCT-Folly' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCTTypeSafety' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRCTTypeSafety' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNAppleAuthentication' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNAppleAuthentication' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCAsyncStorage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNCAsyncStorage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFBApp' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNFBApp' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFBAuth' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNFBAuth' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNGoogleSignin' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNGoogleSignin' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNScreens' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNScreens' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNVectorIcons' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNVectorIcons' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Codegen' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Codegen' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Core' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-CoreModules' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-CoreModules' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Fabric' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Fabric' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-FabricImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-FabricImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-ImageManager' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-ImageManager' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Mapbuffer' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Mapbuffer' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-NativeModulesApple' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-NativeModulesApple' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAnimation' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTAnimation' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAppDelegate' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTAppDelegate' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTBlob' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTBlob' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTFabric' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTFabric' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTLinking' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTLinking' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTNetwork' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTNetwork' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTSettings' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTSettings' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTText' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTText' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTVibration' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTVibration' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-cxxreact' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-cxxreact' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-debug' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-debug' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-graphics' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-graphics' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-hermes' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-hermes' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jserrorhandler' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jserrorhandler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsi' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsi' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsiexecutor' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsiexecutor' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsinspector' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsinspector' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-logger' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-logger' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-nativeconfig' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-nativeconfig' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-perflogger' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-perflogger' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-rendererdebug' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-rendererdebug' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-runtimescheduler' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-runtimescheduler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-utils' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-utils' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'ReactCommon' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReactCommon' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RecaptchaInterop' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRecaptchaInterop' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'SocketRocket' in project 'Pods' via options '-lSocketRocket' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Yoga' in project 'Pods' via options '-lYoga' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'fmt' in project 'Pods' via options '-lfmt' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'glog' in project 'Pods' via options '-lglog' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'libevent' in project 'Pods' via options '-llibevent' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'nanopb' in project 'Pods' via options '-lnanopb' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'react-native-fbsdk-next' in project 'Pods' via options '-lreact-native-fbsdk-next' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'react-native-safe-area-context' in project 'Pods' via options '-lreact-native-safe-area-context' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
Target 'Pods-LoginProject' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'AppAuth' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FBAEMKit' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FBLazyVector' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FBReactNativeSpec' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FBSDKCoreKit' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FBSDKCoreKit_Basics' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FBSDKGamingServicesKit' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FBSDKLoginKit' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FBSDKShareKit' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Firebase' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FirebaseAnalytics' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FirebaseAuth' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCore' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCoreInternal' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FirebaseInstallations' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Boost-iOSX' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper-DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Fmt' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Folly' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Glog' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'Flipper-PeerTalk' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'FlipperKit' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'GTMAppAuth' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'GTMSessionFetcher' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'GoogleSignIn' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'GoogleUtilities' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'OpenSSL-Universal' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'PromisesObjC' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RCT-Folly' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RCTRequired' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RCTTypeSafety' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNAppleAuthentication' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNCAsyncStorage' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNFBApp' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNFBAuth' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNGoogleSignin' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNScreens' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'RNVectorIcons' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-Codegen' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-CoreModules' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-Fabric' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-FabricImage' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-ImageManager' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-Mapbuffer' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-NativeModulesApple' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTActionSheet' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAnimation' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAppDelegate' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTBlob' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTFabric' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTImage' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTLinking' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTNetwork' in project 'Pods'
➜ Explicit depe

I am getting this issue in only iOS physical devices in the iOS simulator and for Android(both Physical device and emulator), it's working fine.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ybcA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As so often, I have no freaking idea why this happens, but it happened to me, and what helped:

```
cd ios
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Why it helped? No freaking idea.